# How to express "a 180-degree ocean view"

Tags: expressions

I just sent this message:

> Au fait, j'ai pu prendre un jour de congé pour la première fois depuis un moment, alors on a dîné dans un restau italien atmosphérique qui **{donnait OU donne} sur la mer avec une vue à plus de 180 degrés**.
>
> La dernière fois, tu as eu la bonté de partager une photo de la mer en France (merci, d'ailleurs !), alors je te rends la pareille.

I wonder what is an idiomatic way to express the idea of "a restaurant with a 180-degree ocean view". I find my phrasing somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written something like:

> …dans un resto avec une atmosphère authentiquement italienne et une vue sur la mer sur plus de 180 degrés.

You can't say *restau atmosphérique* in French. While *atmosphere* meanings are identical between English and French, *atmosphérique* is commonly used in a technical/scientific/wheather forecast context but not when referring to a mood and anything emotional.

Comment: À trancher une bonne fois pour toutes : j'hésitais entre trois prepositions : « avec une vue **à/de/sur** 180 degrés ». « Sur » est donc la seule que l’on puisse employer, là ? Merci.

Comment: Oui, c'est l'expression habituelle. « une vue de la mer » est possible mais un peu ambigu, « vue à la mer » est un barbarisme.

Comment: Hmm, je n'ai pas répondu à la question, « vue à 180° » est correct, « vue sur 180° » moyen et « vue de 180° » ne se dit pas.

Comment: Merci. In my original sentence, I wasn't sure if I should use "donnait" because the fact that the restaurant overlooks the sea continues to the present day. But then again, I was also concerned about the mismatch between "a dîné" and "donne". What's your take on the correct tense? (even if "donnant" may well be the best way to phrase this part...)

Comment: I would have used *donnait* for sequence of tense reasons, but of course the present is also possible as the view is more than likely the same when you write the message.

Comment: I see. Which makes me wonder which tense I should go for in an exam, then? Merci.

Comment: Imperfect: the message is describing the view as it was when you were there.